# Limit of power series with L'Hospital

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, summation, power-series

Calculate the given limit: $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1}{1-\cos(x^2)}\sum_{n=4}^\infty\ n^5x^n$$

First, I used Taylor Expansion (near $x=0$): $$1-\cos(x^2)\approx 0.5x^4$$
I'm now quite stuck with the sum. I can derive $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\ x^n = \frac{1}{1-x}$$
five times in order the get the upper sum, but I'm not sure that's the right way... (very long)

Comment: @egreg the series converges for $x \in (-1,1).$

Comment: $1-\cos(x^2) = 0.5x^4$ False

Comment: @zhw First term in the expansion, why not?

Comment: Because those expressions are not equal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT:**

Recall that we have $1-\cos(x^2)=\frac12 x^4(1+O(x^4))$ so that

$$\frac{1}{1-\cos(x^2)}=\frac{2}{x^4}+O(1)$$

---

**SPOILER ALERT** Scroll over the highlighted area to reveal the solution

> We have $$\begin{align}\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{1-\cos(x^2)}\sum_{n=4}^\infty n^5x^n&=\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{2}{x^4}+O(1)\right)\sum_{n=4}^\infty n^5x^n\\\\&=\lim_{x\to 0}\left(2\cdot4^5+O(x)\right)\\\\&=2\cdot 4^5\end{align}$$

Comment: How did you get $\lim_{x\to 0}(2\cdot 4^5 + O(x))$?

Comment: @Elimination Multiply out the first few terms of the product of the series and the big O representation of $(1-\cos(x^2))^{-1}$. ;-)) - Mark

Answer (score 0):

I don't think L'Hopital is a good way to go here. I would use i) $1-\cos x^2 = x^4/2 + O(x^8),$ and ii) the power series defines a function on $(-1,1)$ that has the form $4^5x^4 + x^5g(x),$ where $g$ is continuous at $0.$